# FutureBuilder only works in Debug

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a FutureBuilder with a ListView to display custom items (Widgets) with values which are read from .txt files.

The problem is that these items are only displayed if I launch the app in Debug-mode or run-mode. When I try to open the app with the AppLauncher (like a "normal" user would do it) the listView is empty. I tried this on an AVD and on a "real" device.

the Future "listFuture" is used to read the values from the files and return a list of Widgets

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future listFuture = setupList();

  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState() {
    print("init complete");
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}
```

If the FutureBuilder gets the data correctly a listView with the list of my widgets should be displayed

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<SubListItem>>(
                      future: widget.listFuture,
                      // ignore: missing_return
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                          case ConnectionState.none:
                            return new Text("None");
                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return new Text("loading");
                          default:
                            if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              print("Error");
                              return Center(child: (Text("No data")));
                            } else {
                              return subListView(context, snapshot);
                            }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

```
Widget subListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  List<Widget> items = snapshot.data;

  //This ScrollConfiguration is used to remove any animations while scrolling
  return ScrollConfiguration(
    behavior: CustomScrollBehavior(),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
      child: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[items[index]],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. You just have to call "setState" when your Widget is built.

```
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      //This setState is necessary because it refreshes the listView
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Comment: No, you don't need that kind of hack, checj my updated answer

Comment: I am sorry but this still doesn't work in my case. Maybe this is the solution for other people but not for me. But still thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like a async data issue, try these changes:

- Remove `listFuture` from your `StatefulWidget`.
- Add the `listFuture` var inside your `State`.
- Move the `setupList()` method inside your `State`.
- And finally call directly like this:

```
child: FutureBuilder<List<SubListItem>>(
                      future: setupList(),
                      // ignore: missing_return
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                           if(!snapshot.hasData) {

                            return new Text("loading");
                           }
                           else  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              print("Error");
                              return Center(child: (Text("No data")));
                            } else {
                              return subListView(context, snapshot);
                            }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: I already tries this but I discovered a new error if you open the app over the applauncher and navigate to a new page (Navigator.push) and then press the back button the ListView is displayed correctly.